# Can I redo Netherverse Challenges after I complete them in story mode?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-into-the-nexus

There are 18 skill points associated with the challenges and each challenge only shows up once in the game (as far as I have seen). I don't want to have to keep restarting the game to be able to try them again. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. In New Game+, after you acquire your ship, a new 'planet' is on the planet select screen. This allows you to replay any of the Netherverse levels that you have discovered up that point.